# Iterative Solution for Summing Nested Lists

Tags: python

Does anyone have an iterative solution to find the sum of nested lists such as this one:

```
ls = [1, 2, [3, 4], [5, [[6, 7], 8]], 9]
```

I have a working recursive solution, but I would love to see how we could go about doing this iteratively!

Thanks!

Comment: If unmaintainable solutions are acceptable !: `import re;ls = [1, 2, [3, 4], [5, [[6, 7], 8]], 9];print(sum(map(int, re.findall("\d+", str(ls)))))`

Answer (score 3):

```py
ls = [1, 2, [3, 4], [5, [[6, 7], 8]], 9]

index = 0
total = 0
while index < len(ls):
    item = ls[index]
    if isinstance(item, list):
        ls += item
    else:
        total += item

    index += 1

print(total)
```

`45`

This solution works by iteratively going through every list element, and splitting the behavior in two:

- if a number is encountered it is added to the total (`total+=item`)
- if a list is encountered, its contents are copied at the end of the input list (`ls`) and the iteration continues to the next element.

When the end of the original list is reached (so after the number `9` in this case), the loop starts to encounter the lists that were copied before, and simply keeps summing or concatenating the values until finished.

Edit: using @Tomerikoo advice, an improved version that keeps the code as self-documenting would be

```py
ls = [1, 2, [3, 4], [5, [[6, 7], 8]], 9]

total = 0
for item in ls:
    if isinstance(item, list):
        ls += item
    else:
        total += item

print(total)
```

Comment: Thanks so much Luca! Do you mind explaining the bit when you add the item to your ls? I'm still new to this and would love to understand the thinking behind it.

Comment: no problem, I tried to be clear instead of concise, but a lot of stuff can be squeezed if you are looking towards efficiency/speed

Comment: BTW, you can also just do `for item in ls` instead of the `while` loop and maintaining this `index` variable

Comment: I see. So, we are basically going into each nested list and just putting it at the back of the list. We will keep on iterating through this "growing" list, adding all the values we find within each nested list to the back of our current list. We will then add these values (which are no longer in lists) to our total sum. Is that correct?

Comment: I noticed my comment wasn't really correct, but I loved the solution! The idea of getting the needed values to add to our sum by adding the list to another list, essentially copying that nested list to the back of our current list (while removing one layer of the lists away by doing list + list) is a cool way of doing it; thanks for sharing! :)

Comment: I just want to say that this is a very nice solution and I didn't think about it, and now with your explanations this is a great answer as well. Well done! You got my upvote. Just a small correction: In the second bullet you say *if a list is encountered, it is copied at the end* - this is not accurate and would be useless if was true. It is not copied at the end, **its content** is copied at the end. The `+` operator on lists is equivalen to the `extend` method, not `append`

Answer (score 1):

Is this acceptable?

```py
ls = [1, 2, [3, 4], [5, [[6, 7], 8]], 9]

def add(buffer):
  total = 0
  while buffer:
    e = buffer.pop()
    if isinstance(e, list):
      buffer.extend([item for item in e])
    else:
      total += e
  return total

print(add(ls))
```

Comment: this is recursive

Comment: Hey there! It's a really nice recursive solution, but I was hoping for an iterative solution! :)

Comment: You can probably use the ls directly instead of using the buffer-type and don't need to put the item for item in e in a list as we are already extending it into a list. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import deque

def func(ls):
    nested = deque(ls)
    sol = []
    deq = deque()
    while nested or deq:
        a = deq.pop() if deq else nested.popleft()
        deq.extend(reversed()) if isinstance(a, list) else sol.append(a)
    return sol
```

This might work. We are essentially flatenning our list.Dequeues are being used for better time complexity and performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
ls = [1, 2, [3, 4], [5, [[6, 7], 8]], 9]
next_loop = True
while next_loop:
  next_loop = False
  for i in ls:
      if isinstance(i, list):
          for y in i:
              ls.append(y)
          ls.remove(i)
          next_loop = True
print(sum(ls))
```

This will ouput

```
45
```